# Expo Go Build failing [stderr] E401

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I trying to build application in react native using expo go.
I cant understand why its failing
Why when I am trying to build application I getting error:

```
Running "npm install" in the root dir of your repository 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! code
[stderr] 
E401
[stderr] 
npm ERR!
[stderr] 
Incorrect or missing password.
[stderr] 
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
[stderr] 
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
[stderr] 
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
[stderr] 
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
[stderr] 
npm ERR! 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
[stderr] 
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     npm login
[stderr] 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2023-06-04T19_27_54_132Z-debug-0.log
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

[image]

I tired even to start empty project and build in expo and nothing works.
Which login and password is needed ?
I can build app on my local and even in "expo updates" everything works but when I want to build app on expo server its failing.

Link to source code